# How to make Spring-data-mongo skip over null @DBRef for a List<Entity>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb, morphia

We have a large Spring Boot app using a Mongo database, and we are migrating our ORM from Morphia to Spring-data-mongo. In Morphia, they have an [annotation](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.2/references.html) `@Reference(ignoreMissing = true)` which we use for our DBRefs. When we use the `@Reference` annotation on a `List<Entity>`, Morphia will [skip over](https://github.com/MorphiaOrg/morphia/blob/1.6.x/morphia/src/main/java/dev/morphia/mapping/ReferenceMapper.java#L168) any null refs (ie refs it cannot load), which helps avoid nulls in our list items.

Sample of our existing model class:

```
public class Book {
    @Reference(ignoreMissing = true)
    private List<Author> authors;
}
```

We are trying to reproduce the same behavior with Spring-data-mongo's `@DBRef` annotation, but by default Spring is always including the null dbrefs in the `List<Entity>` class members that we have.

To resolve this, as a start, I tried overriding the `DbRefResolver.bulkFetch` [method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/4.2.x/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/DefaultDbRefResolver.java#L96) Spring uses for resolving DBRefs:

```
public class CustomDbRefResolver extends DefaultDbRefResolver {
    public CustomDbRefResolver(MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory) {
        super(mongoDbFactory);
    }

    @Override
    @NotNull
    public List<Document> bulkFetch(@NotNull List<DBRef> refs) {
        var docs = super.bulkFetch(refs);
        return docs.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(toList());
    }
}
```

But looking deep into [Spring's implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/4.2.x/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MappingMongoConverter.java#L1715), they don't use this method at all if the list of DBRefs only has 1 element in it:

```
List<Document> referencedRawDocuments = dbrefs.size() == 1
        ? Collections.singletonList(readRef(dbrefs.iterator().next()))
        : bulkReadRefs(dbrefs);
```

So now I'm stuck on how to make Spring ignore the null DBRefs for any-size list like how Morphia does it?

(I checked the [javadocs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/3.4.0/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/DBRef.html) and there doesn't seem to be an ignore property like Morphia has)

Comment: A close vote? No question on stackoverflow has an answer for this problem so it is new material

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since Spring doesn't call `bulkFetch` for Collections of size 1, I ditched the `CustomDbRefResolver` and overrode the higher-level `MappingMongoConverter` instead. The `DBRefResolver`'s methods get invoked during the execution of `MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray` which can be overridden:

```java
import com.mongodb.DBRef; //make sure to use the right import!

public class CustomMappingMongoConverter extends MappingMongoConverter {
    public CustomMappingMongoConverter(DbRefResolver dbRefResolver, MappingContext<? extends MongoPersistentEntity<?>, MongoPersistentProperty> mappingContext) {
        super(dbRefResolver, mappingContext);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object readCollectionOrArray(ConversionContext context, Collection<?> source, TypeInformation<?> targetType) {
        var readResult = super.readCollectionOrArray(context, source, targetType);
        if (source.isEmpty()
                || !(source.stream().findAny().orElse(null) instanceof DBRef)
                || !(readResult instanceof List)
                || ((List<?>) readResult).isEmpty()
        ) {
            return readResult;
        }
        var list = ((List<?>) readResult);
        return list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(toList());
    }
}
```

In order to use this converter with spring-data-mongodb, I had to override this part of my MongoConfiguration:

```java
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    @Override
    @Bean
    @NotNull
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter(MongoDatabaseFactory databaseFactory,
                                                       MongoCustomConversions customConversions,
                                                       MongoMappingContext mappingContext) {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(databaseFactory);
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new CustomMappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mappingContext);
        converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions);
        converter.setCodecRegistryProvider(databaseFactory);
        return converter;
    }
}
```